# unwind segue from UIViewController with container view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview, unwind-segue

I have a segue from `AViewController` to `BViewController`. In `BViewController`, I put a back button and a Container View. This Container View are connected with a `UITableViewController`.

I want to perform an unwind segue from `BViewController` to `AViewController`, by pressing the back button in `BViewController` (outside the Container View).

I put this code in `AViewController`.

```
@IBAction func unwindToTop(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

After than, I also Ctrl Click the back button to unwind action. Unfortunately, after I build the app, and I click the back button, an error was appear. Can anyone help me with this issue?

thank you so much for your help

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error code. here it is :

`Thread 1 : EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`

==> in debug, i got this :
`(lldb)`

Comment: You should put the `unwindToTop` method to `AViewController` and then connect the button to exit and find `unwindToTop`

Comment: ups, sorry again. I put the `unwindToTop` in `AViewController`, not `BViewCOntroller`

I will change my question